# rails as_json only: rendering not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have the following and am not sure why it doesn't work. It outputs the whole location object.

```
def test
  @l=Location.find(12)
  render :json => @l.as_json(only: [:id, :name])
end
```

How do I limit to only id and name? I don't want to use respond_to or respond_with block.

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?

```
render json: { location: { id: @l.id, name: @l.name } }
```

I want to edit my answer. I think this is the correct way to do it.

```
render json: @l.to_json(only: [:id, :name])
```

Comment: thx. this works but how would I add syntax for an array of locations such as Location.all

Comment: I think the syntax would be: `render json: {locations: Location.all.map { |l| {id: l.id, name: l.name} } }`

Answer (score 0):

you can use ActiveRecord::Base's to_json method like this

```
render :json => @l.to_json(:only => [:id, :name])
```